# RabbitMQ: Priority of unacknowledged messages

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

If a message is unacknowledged, does it go to the front of the queue, or is it added to the end of the queue?

Comment: I believe its the front of the queue.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363302/rabbitmq-message-order-of-delivery

Comment: It remains at the front of the queue.