# Understanding unacked message requeue order

Tags: concurrency, rabbitmq, messaging, amqp

First of all, I quote the following text from [RabbitMQ docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html):

> When a message is requeued, it will be placed to its original position
>   in its queue, if possible. **If not (due to concurrent deliveries and
>   acknowledgements from other consumers when multiple consumers share a
>   queue), the message will be requeued to a position closer to queue
>   head**.

Now imagine that there're two message (A and B) on the same queue, both are *unacked*: when official docs says "[...] closer to queue head" gives any guarantee of ordering?

Would message A be queued before B under any condition? For me the answer is *no* but I'm looking for advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RabbitMQ - Message order of delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363302/rabbitmq-message-order-of-delivery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is

- if both A and B are requeued, and
- A was originally added to the queue before B, and
- there is no consumer active on the queue between the time A was requeued and B was requeued,

then A will *always* be placed before B in the queue after both have been re-queued.

See [my answer here for explanation as to why these assumptions are necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363302/rabbitmq-message-order-of-delivery/21363518#21363518).