# SQL Server Race Condition on Round Robin Process Queue

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, race-condition

### TL;DR

SQL Server race condition on a round-robin process queue despite adding `ROWLOCK`, `READPAST`, and `UPDLOCK` hints in conjunction with application locks.

---

I have an application where multiple app servers and multiple processes run "jobs" that are stored in a queue-like table in our SQL Server 2014 database. Every x number of seconds, each process queries the table for new jobs to run (if the process is available to take jobs). New jobs need to be assigned in something like a round-robin fashion on a user-to-user basis. The problem is that my current query is running into a race condition so that multiple processes are acting on the same job, resulting in duplicate data sets in our output tables. This is what the current query looks like:

```
EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = 'GetJobAssignments', @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @LockOwner = 'Session';
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT TOP (@nMaxJobs) [JobId]
        ,[Owner]
        ,[Timeout]
        ,[StartTime]
        ,[Status]
        ,[userID] 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [userID] ORDER BY [JobID]) AS [recID] 
    FROM [Jobs]
    WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST, UPDLOCK)
    WHERE [Status] = 0 AND [Owner] is null
    ORDER BY [recID], [userID]
    )
    UPDATE cte SET [Owner] = @owner, [Status] = 1;
COMMIT;
EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'GetJobAssignments', @LockOwner = 'Session';
```

I have tried various combinations of `ROWLOCK`, `READPAST`, `UPDLOCK`, and `XLOCK` with no luck. Also used with and without the applock on both `Session` and `Transaction` settings. In other iterations of the query I messed around with putting the transaction isolation level to `REPEATABLE READ` and `SERIALIZABLE` with equal measures of no success.

Bearing in mind that I am neither an SQL nor a SQLServer expert, this next part might not mean anything...I have tried doing this within a stored procedure (as it is now), but in the past it has also been called from EF5 using `dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` (it is now just a stored procedure that is part of the dbContext).

This current query is the result of messing around with a couple known working answers to questions similar to this:

[SQL Server Process Queue Race Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939831/sql-server-process-queue-race-condition/940001#940001)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81791/strategies-for-checking-out-records-for-processing

Outside of basic research on the things I have mentioned here, I am pretty unfamiliar with strategies in SQL Server to prevent deadlocks/race conditions. Are there any other options that I could try in my query, or are there any known preconditions that might exist that I could check for that would prevent this current strategy from working?

Comment: Instead of wasting a bunch of time trying to do something with a database server that it probably never will do well, why not just use a message broker, e.g. RabbiMQ?

Comment: @theMayer would it be easy to drop in RabbitMQ and implement implement for this use case? In my case there are several servers that use a DB to communicate. Can RabbitMQ be set up as a message queue accessible over ip?

Comment: @seebiscuit Yes, that's what it was meant for.

Comment: As you are using `sp_getapplock` in exclusive mode only one concurrent connection will be able to execute that bit of code. There must be something else going on.

Comment: @MartinSmith do you mean something else like another `UPDATE` being made somewhere in the application? This is the only update that modifies the job owner in the application.

Comment: @theMayer I'm combing through the documentation now to see if rules can be set, but it looks like the round-robin used by RabbitMQ is prioritized by default by FIFO, where I want to prioritize by user first, then by queue entry

Comment: @NickTallents - If by queue entry, you mean FIFO, then yes. If you need by user, you would have to create a queue per user, then consume in priority order from among the several
 queues.

Comment: @NickTallents - as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363302/rabbitmq-message-order-of-delivery/21363518#21363518) illustrates, relying upon order of processing when you have multiple consumers is tenuous at best.