# Consuming parallel SQS Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, message-queue, amazon-sqs

In my Aws SQS Fifo queue I have:

`A, 
B, 
C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, ... ,C100
D`

What I would like to do is process in order exactly A, B, Cn and D but C can be consumed parallel.

Is there a way to guarantee the order of consuming by providing parallelism for C groups?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RabbitMQ - Message order of delivery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363302/rabbitmq-message-order-of-delivery)

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363302/rabbitmq-message-order-of-delivery) points out, there is no way to ensure order of processing when you have multiple consumers operating in parallel, and attempting to synchronize the parallel consumers will have the effect of using a serial consumer.

While the answer referenced was oriented to RabbitMQ, the general principles apply regardless of queuing system.