# RabbitMQ - Message posted to Topic exchange - Consumer not receiving in same order

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging

I have the implementation where one micro service post message to topic. There is only one consumer bounded to topic from another microservice. I assumed that message posted to the topic would be routed to the bounded queue in the same order, but I ran into issue where message come in out of order.

Is my assumption correct? Do I need configure anything on rabbitmq so that topic route message in order?

Comment: RabbitMQ will deliver messages in order, so the only way to help is to be able to reproduce your environment to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. I confirmed from documentation that for version greater than 2.7, the strict order is maintained. Digging more at the code, it looks like the consumer hits the synchronized block and then lost its ordering.

Comment: [You should not count on messages being delivered or processed in any particular order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363302/rabbitmq-message-order-of-delivery/21363518#21363518). See linked answer. You can think about it, but just don’t do it.